# Docker container image cant access postgresql DB Connection to localhost:5432 refused

Tags: spring, postgresql, docker, containers

I'm running a PostgreSQL as a native app(NOT CONTAINER) on my localhost
I'm able to connect to it with an SQL client.

While I'm running a spring application - in a container
the app starts and fails while trying to connect the database

```
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Connection to localhost:5432 refused. 
Check that the hostname and port are correct and that the postmaster is accepting TCP/IP connections.
```

in my docker image, I have used expose to open the port, but it still won't work

```
EXPOSE 8080 8443 4000 5432
```

What can i do to fix it

I run my image with

```
docker run ec0bdea074a6
```

Tried also

```
docker run -p 5432:5432/tcp -p 5432:5432/udp ec0bdea074a6
```

And it didnt work as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changes the url from localhost to

```
host.docker.internal
```

Meaning:

```
  dw.url=jdbc:postgresql://host.docker.internal:5432/DW
```

Answer (score 0):

`EXPOSE` acts as documentation, just like comments in the Dockerfile. You need to use `-p` flag in the `docker run` command. See the docs for more details: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#expose

Comment: Some tools hook into EXPOSE, though. So it's a bit more than documentation. It's more like a label.

Comment: @oartart  didnt solve the issue, still failing with the same error

docker run -p 5432:5432/tcp  -p 5432:5432/udp ec0bdea074a6